# How to pattern match on Row with null values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm wondering why I cant pattern match on a Spark (2.1) Row containing null values (Strings):

```
val r = Row(null:String)

r match {case Row(s:String) => println("row is null")}
```

> scala.MatchError: [null] (of class
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Row` doesn't really play an important role here, we can simplify:

```
val r = null: String

r match {case s:String => println("s is null")}
```

You can check the pattern match still fails. This is because type patterns like `s: String` are [specifically defined not to match `null`](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns):

> A type pattern T is of one of the following forms:

> - A reference to a class C, p.C, or T#C. This type pattern matches **any non-null instance** of the given class...

`isInstanceOf` behaves like this too: `null.isInstanceOf[String]` is `false`.

So if you want to match `null`, you can

1. use exactly `null` as the pattern:

   r match {
   case s: String => println("r is not null")
   case null => println("r is null")
   }
2. use a "catch-all" pattern like `_` or a variable:

   r match {
   case s: String => println("r is not null")
   case s => println("matches only if r is null or not a String")
   }

Or if we put `Row` back, you'd write

```
r match {
  case Row(s: String) => println("r contains non-null")
  case Row(null) => println("r contains null")
}
```

Comment: As much as I agree with you, your answer might sound a bit confusing for some :)

Comment: I've expanded the answer, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It now makes sense to me. But it makes things more complicate  because my Row hase multiple nullable fields which I just want to map as they are, so I don't want to match all possible combinations of null/not-null cases. But I guess this would be separate question

Comment: You can simply use variables for those cases and then check them inside the branch. Or `getAs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the pattern should be to match `Row(null)` exactly.

```
scala> r match { case Row(null) => "matched" }
res1: String = matched
```

You're right that the more generic pattern won't work.

```
scala> r match { case Row(s: String) => "matched" }
scala.MatchError: [null] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow)
  ... 50 elided
```

I **think** that's because `null` gives you `Any` type to match to (and there's some type magic involved I can't explain exactly).

```
scala> Row.unapplySeq(r)
res2: Some[Seq[Any]] = Some(WrappedArray(null))
```